# How to write entry into the System Event Log (SEL) via ipmitool?

Tags: hardware, ipmi, ipmitool

I see in the ipmitool there is an "add" command in the sel menu.  It wants a file, but what format for that file is it expecting?

```
> ipmitool sel add file.txt
> Invalid Event: 0000f8b601000000
```

From the doc: http://man.he.net/man1/ipmitool

> add
>
> ```
>                  Read  event  entries from a file and add them to the SEL.
>                  New SEL entries area added onto the SEL  after  the  last
>                  record  in  the  SEL.   Record  added is of type 2 and is
>                  automatically timestamped.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The format of the file is the same as output by `ipmitool sel save {filename}` and looks like this:

```
0x04 0x10 0x07 0x6f 0x02 0xff 0xff # Event Logging Disabled #0x07 Log area reset/cleared
0x04 0x12 0x83 0x6f 0x05 0x00 0xff # System Event #0x83 Timestamp Clock Sync
0x04 0x12 0x83 0x6f 0x05 0x80 0xff # System Event #0x83 Timestamp Clock Sync
0x04 0x09 0x01 0x6f 0x00 0xff 0xff # Power Unit #0x01 Power off/down
0x04 0x09 0x01 0xef 0x00 0xff 0xff # Power Unit #0x01 Power off/down
0x04 0x14 0x09 0x6f 0x00 0xff 0xff # Button #0x09 Power Button pressed
```

Loading this into the SEL will log events with the current date/time.

Compare output of `ipmitool sel save {filename}` with `ipimitool sel writeraw {filename}` to determine the byte mapping above.